# How can I implement native c++ scripting like it's done in engines like Unreal and Godot?

Tags: c++, godot, unreal, scripting, dll

I've been developing my own game engine and I'm kind of stuck in the process of scripting. I decided to use C++, since my game engine is mainly written in C++. (and don't suggest me other languages as the scripting backend please) I want to know how game engines like Unreal or Godot are doing this since C++ is a compiled language. I slightly know that this is possible with dynamic link libraries, but I don't understand the way it's supposed to do. It'd be really helpful if you could provide me an example. So basically I need a custom script that has a class which inherits from the `Entity` class from the engine. And each frame, I want to call the update function in that class. I tried `GetProcAddress` from the `window.h` header, but it apparently doesn't work on classes and to make things worse, conversion from a `FARPROC (windows procAddress)` to a function pointer is restricted in c++ :(

Comment: This question really boils down to "how do I get a class instance from a DLL?" which is a general programming question unrelated to game development. You would probably get better answers on https://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I think having an example of how it can be done in a game/engine is perfectly on-topic for a game development site.

Comment: Unreal's source code is available on GitHub. It might be helpful to take a peek at the LiveCoding module to see how they do it there.